# Set Transparent Highlight in combobox selection?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, highlight

I'm trying to achieve a transparent highlight of the combobox, when a user moves mouse over an item. I need it to be transparent since every item in the combobox already has a color that is shown as background in the drop down menu.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" FontWeight="ExtraBold">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">Transparent</SolidColorBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}">Black</SolidColorBrush>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="Agriculture">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
```

with this code i only get white color which covers the background of the highlighted item, as so:
[image: Forestry is white, when it should be gray]

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the Color of the SolidColorBrush to Silver or something and also set its Opacity property to a value less than 1:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Opacity="0.4" Color="Silver" />
```

The HighlightBrushKey won't be applied "over" the default SolidColorBrushes of the ComboBoxItems though. It will replace these rather than overlaying them.

Comment: tried it, still ends up just being white :/ looks like there is no way around it, I'll just have to work with this @mm8

Comment: What colour do you expect/want it to have? Just set the Color property of the Brush to this one. I am afraid there is no such thing as a "transparent highlight" color or brush.

Comment: yep, rgb doesn't support transparency, it works with opacity, so i shall try and make several changes, see how it works, tnx for your patience in any case :))
@mm8